# ArcGIS web map in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, arcgis

I want to implement an ArcGIS web map in my winform C# application. I have found a bunch of resources for doing this in a WPF application, but nothing for the winform platform. I have an API-Key from ArcGIS and have already made a webmap.

Does anyone know if this is even possible or do I need to use WPF to do this? I have tried the GMap open source, and it does support some maps from ArcGIS, but I have not figured out how to add "custom" webmaps from a link. I would also need to add credentials to my example.

F.eks
Map.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.ArcGIS_World_Street_MapProvider.Instance;

Edit,
Sadly it seems that the best solution is to implement a wpf controller into the winform application.

Comment: You can host a WPF control in WinForms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a world map, I don't know what you're planning on doing with it so if you just want to display a world map then I found a YouTube tutorial about this that might help,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxSJJfaAzKg

If you want an interactive map and arcgis does that for you then you can emulate a WPF control inside a winforms application,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfpzVDAJ1fE

Sorry if I'm only showing YouTube videos as sources instead of actual documentation, but at least it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the Esri ArcGIS Runtime SDK to do this. Yes it is a WPF control, but that's no problem. You'll need to use the ElementHost to host WPF content inside the WinForms view, and this is fully supported but the runtime. Just be aware that WinForms uses software rendering, so you don't get as good performance as you would with a pure WPF, UWP or WinUI3 window.
So you'll just follow all the doc found on how to do it in WPF, then render that part of the view inside the ElementHost of your WinForms app.

WinForms Element host doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?view=net-5.0

Conceptual doc/examples of hosting WPF in WinForms:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-creating-new-wpf-content-on-windows-forms-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-3-d-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

/Morten Nielsen - Dev Lead (ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET)